# Read float number from Postgres without rounding

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

this might seem a very naive question but I am having a hard time to figure this out. I have a float value `37.50378` in my PostgreSQL database. When I am trying to fetch this value in my Nodejs application it gives me `37.5038`. I want to fetch the exact number without rounding off the decimal digits. How do I do that? 
The data type of the column in Postgres is `Real`.

**EDIT**

I am using Knex schema builder and using `float(column, precision, scale)` to create a column(to store above-said value). I have tried different numbers for `precision` and `scale` just in case that's causing the above-said behavior. But every time I tried to fetch the value `37.50378`, all I get back is `37.5038`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `double(column)` in knex, which is translated to double precision in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `real` 4-byte precision. See [PostgreSQL Numeric Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html).

It's got nothing to do with Node.js or its PostgreSQL driver.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vitaly-t. I am using Knex.js for building the schema and `float(column, precision, scale)` to create the column. No matter what precision and scale number I provide it always create a column with data type `real` in Postgres. Do I need to change anything in my schema building?

Comment: @harsh that's an entirely separate question. I'm not familiar with knex to answer that.

Comment: No problem @vitaly-t. Thanks for your input.